# running grub-install during arch installation gives the error "no space left on device". How can I solve this?

Tags: linux, grub, uefi, arch-linux, boot-partition

I'm dual booting windows 11 and arch linux (i'm installing arch right now).

I have created a single partition for /mnt (i created a swapfile in the same partition instead of creating a separate partition) and mounted the EFI partition on /mnt/boot, just like the installation guide says. Once I chroot into /mnt and get to the point where I need to install grub I get the error message:

```
grub-install: error: cannot copy '/usr/share/locale/en@quot/LC\_MESSAGES/grub.mo' to '/boot/grub/locale/en@quot.mo': No space left on device.
```

I tried googling it and came across this issue https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=234954, and following the first answer, to make space I removed `UEFI HTTPs boot` from the list given by `efibootmgr -v`, but the problem still persists with the same error message...

the list from "efibootmgr -v" is now just this: the windows boot manager, the usb stick i used as installation media, and this `UEFI RST KBG50ZNS1T02 NVMe KIOXIA 1024GB Z2FPC3S3Q6DK`... Can I remove this last option like I did for the "UEFI HTTPs Boot" option or will I make a mess? Will it even help? It says 1024GB, and my hard drive is 1TB, so I guess that's my hard drive (does it make sense? Is it necessary?)

I don't know what to do... Any help??

This photo is how it's all looking at the moment (sorry for the low quality, I couldn't do better): https://imgur.com/a/33Mkc8k

I checked the /etc/fstab file, and the boot partition has `errors=remount-ro` part which I read could be an issue, though I don't know if I have to change that directly or do something else. I don't even know if I can reboot the pc and try to work on it later.

I also read about some Bootx64.efi file but again, i don't know what I'm supposed to do with it.

EDIT: I rebooted the pc and went back into windows and the ESP is indeed full (195MB out of 200MB, which is already pretty small according to the wiki), but even with third party software like AOMEI I can't merge unallocated space into the ESP, which sucks (why can't I do this?). I also discovered that the HTTPs Boot entry wasn't removed at all, it's still very present, so maybe actually removing it will give me enough space for grub... What do I do?
EDIT 2: here is the screenshot of disk management on windows (I deleted the linux partition so I can start from scratch once I figure this out): https://imgur.com/a/MNVhxku

Comment: Please add a screenshot of Disk Management in Windows.

Comment: I added the link in the post

Comment: I found this video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmIlfKYU5cQ, would it work if I followed the steps? Is it a problem that at the end the new EFI partition is not the first on the disk?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the ESP to more than 500 MB.
You do have a large unallocated space following `C:`, but `C:` stands
between it and the ESP. You need to move `C:` down by at least 500 MB
to create unallocated space following the ESP. You may then resize
the ESP to include this new space.

As Windows has no tools for moving partitions, you will need to use
a third-party partition editor for moving and resizing the
partitions.

**Warning** : Partition editing is dangerous, as any mistake can destroy
your disk. Ensure that you have good backups for your data,
and I also recommend taking an image backup of the entire disk.

An example third-party product that can move and resize partitions is
[AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition Freeware](https://www.diskpart.com/free-partition-manager.html)
or its
[alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-partition-assistant/).

I also recommend
[AOMEI Backupper Free](https://www.aomeitech.com/ab/standard.html)
and its
[Create Bootable Disc Based on Windows PE or Linux](https://www.ubackup.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html),
for taking a disk image and be able to boot to the AOMEI USB disk and
return the image of the previous disk
in case a serious problem occurs, to be able to restore the disk.

This all is a highly technical operation that requires some knowledge
about partitioning.